# what does Slope-Intercept mean?

Tags: calculus

Hi every body please I need your help , my question is what does Slope-Intercept mean ?

Clear example with images would be appreciated.

Thanx evry body.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Slope.E2.80.93intercept_form

Answer (score 2):

We say the equation for a line is in *slope-intercept form* if it is of the form $y = mx + b$ for some numbers $m, b$. The reason we call it this is because $m$ is the slope of the line and $b$ is the $y$-intercept of the line.

Proof: The $y$-intercept is the $y$-component of the point on the line which has $x$-component equal to zero. In other words, just plug in $x=0$ to find the the $y$-intercept. In our equation, we have $y = m(0) + b = b$, i.e. $y=b$ when $x=0$. This is what it means for the line to have a $y$-intercept of $b$.

Likewise, to find the slope, we need to calculate $\frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$ for two points $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)$ which are both on the line. For instance, we could pick $x_1 = 1$ and $x_2 = 2$. Using the equation, this implies that $y_1 = m(1) + b = m+b$ and $y_2 = m(2) + b = 2m + b$. Thus, we have that $$\text{slope} = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1} = \frac{(2m + b) - (m+b)}{2-1} = \frac{m}{1} = m$$ Thus $m$ is the slope of the line.

Answer (score 1):

When a line in the $xy$-plane is given as $y=ax+b$, $a$ is called the *slope*, and $b$ is called the *intercept*. Slope represents "steepness", and the intercept is the point of intersection with the y-axis.

Comment: what does the result of the equation represent ?? for example suppose that a = 5, x= 10, b=3 then the result of this equation will be 53 but what 53 represent.

thank you so much